# Need help displaying only one result per user from database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am making a top 10 list of the best times from my bhop server in csgo. All the times get stored in the database, but the problem is that each time the user gets a new time it adds a new row. With the code i have now it displays the top ten list of all the times, i want it to only display one result per user(the best one)

My current code:

```
<div id="content">
        <table cellspacing="0">
        <h1 align="center">bhop_eazy_csgo</h1>
            <tr><th>Place</th><th>Name</th><th>Time</th></tr>
            <?php
            $i = 1;
                    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","timer");
                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM round WHERE map = 'bhop_eazy_csgo' ORDER BY time LIMIT 0, 10");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                          echo "<tr><td>" . ($i) . "</td><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td> <td>" . gmdate("i:s", $row['time']) . "</td></tr>";
                          $i++;
                    }

                mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
        </table>
</div>
```

How it looks:
http://gyazo.com/3653ec8a87fbf68c4137b67b75e20f8d

**Edit**
Now it looks like this:

> 1 Wildmine 00:49
>  2 Wildmine 00:50
>  3 Wildmine 01:02
>  4
>   ?J@rr3?  01:12

I want it to look like this:

> 1 Wildmine 00:49
>  2 ?J@rr3?  01:12
>   **Thanks to  Michael Wagner for helping me getting it working:)**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
                    SELECT DISTINCT name n, (
                        SELECT time
                        FROM round
                        WHERE map = 'bhop_eazy_csgo'
                        AND name = n
                        ORDER BY time
                        LIMIT 1
                    ) AS time
                    FROM round
                    WHERE map = 'bhop_eazy_csgo'
                    ORDER BY time
                    LIMIT 0 , 10
                    ");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                    echo "<tr><td>" . ($i) . "</td><td>" . $row['n'] . "</td> <td>" . gmdate("i:s", $row['time']) . "</td></tr>";
                    $i++;
```

}

Comment: try LIMIT with ORDER BY

Comment: I recommend you to group data by users, and then apply order and limit. Check this:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Comment: Maybe change your password.

Comment: Not a used password :) But why not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name n, (
    SELECT time
    FROM round
    WHERE map = 'bhop_eazy_csgo'
    AND name = n
    ORDER BY time
    LIMIT 1
) AS time
FROM round
WHERE map = 'bhop_eazy_csgo'
ORDER BY TIME
LIMIT 0 , 10
```